# How to include karma and jasmine to AngularJs project served with webpack

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I spent the whole day trying to setup karma for my project. I went through all the tutorials and StackOverflow but couldn't integrate it into my project.

My project is served using web pack. I guess the problem is that I can't get the reference to my root app module.

Please help me with this.

I tried importing the module using its name, imported the whole files(js) etc but nothing helped.

PS: This project has tons of services, components, directives etc.
We have used js with jade. And this is the first time we are integrating unit testing for a new feature.

---

edited

`karma.config.js`

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = void 0;

const commonsChunkPluginIndex = webpackConfig.plugins.findIndex(plugin => plugin.chunkNames);
webpackConfig.plugins.splice(commonsChunkPluginIndex, 1);

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: false,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 300,

    files: [
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      "./client/app/app.js", ,=== root module
      "./client/app/services/chart-type/cohortSpec.js",  <==  contains test case
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      "./webpack.config.js": ['babel'],
      './client/app/app.js': ['webpack'],
      "./client/app/services/chart-type/cohortSpec.js": ['babel']
    },
    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        "presets": ["es2015"],
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-umd",  "transform-runtime"]
      }
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    }
  });
}
```

> <strike>I can't get the reference to *app* module even though I have imported all js files in the app. Note that webpack serves files at dist/, which isn't imported in karma.config</strike>

With above config, I was able to get the reference to the app.

**Is there any improvement in the config?**

Comment: What you expect as an aswer? Some ready setup karma-webpack-angular? But it is already available on web... Consider posting some code, i.e. karma & webpack config and explain what is actual problem.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov. I sure will, in a while.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov. I have included the config files. Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: which guide you follow? I.e. you didnt mention 'webpack' in your karma.conf.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov. I have made a little progress myself. I have included webpack too.I have updated the config too, and till now it's working. Any improvement/suggestion in the config is welcome.